# how to add sku column in order sales grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, admin, grid

i need to add sku column with filter in order sales grid in magento 2.

[image]

how can i add this can any one have refrence

Answer (score 2):

**1. Create di.xml file at app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\ with following code**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Create Collection.php file at app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\ with the following code**

```
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;
 
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
 
/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected $helper;
 
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }
 
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_item');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id', ['sku']);
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

**3. Create sales_order_grid.xml file app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\ with following code**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="sku" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PurchasedPrice">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>        
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the below extension as a reference and build your own custom module to add SKU in the grid.

https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-ordergrid

https://github.com/mattador/tde-sales-grid

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_OrderProducts

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-add-a-custom-column-to-the-order-grid-in-magento-2.html

Please let me know if you need more details.